# Getting an error when trying to execute powershell code via a SQL Agent job

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I've setup a SQL Server 2016 agent job that has 2 steps that is executed by the same service account, Step 1 executes an SSIS package that writes 2 files out to a  share.  Step 2 executes embedded powershell code that combines these 2 files into a single file and creates a file on that same share where the 2 files were created by SSIS.  When I execute the job, Step 1, the SSIS package completes successfully and creates the 2 files on this share.  But when Step 2 executes I get the error below.  Just a point of info, when I run this script locally from my windows 10 box, I have no issues.

I guess my question is, if SSIS can execute successfully with the same service account can this be a permissions issue for powershell scripts? I'm not a server admin so if this is a stupid questions please forgive my ignorance. Any help/direction anyone can provide would be appreciated.

> Message
>   Executed as user: XXX\sqlsvc02. The job script encountered the following errors. These errors did not stop the script:  A job step received an error at line 12 in a PowerShell script. The corresponding line is 'Get-Content $pathCounts, $pathDetails | Set-Content $outFile'. Correct the script and reschedule the job. The error information returned by PowerShell is: '**Cannot find path '\xxx\shared\MonthlyReports\BoundPoliciesAddedAtFaultEndorsementWithin10Days_Counts.csv' because it does not exist.**  '  A job step received an error at line 12 in a PowerShell script. The corresponding line is 'Get-Content $pathCounts, $pathDetails | Set-Content $outFile'. Correct the script and reschedule the job. The error information returned by PowerShell is: '**Cannot find path '\xxx\shared\MonthlyReports\BoundPoliciesAddedAtFaultEndorsementWithin10Days_Details.csv' because it does not exist.**  '.  Process Exit Code 0.  The step succeeded.

Here is my powershell script:

```
# Define variables
$path = '\\xxx\shared\MonthlyReports'
$pathCounts = Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath 'BoundPoliciesAddedAtFaultEndorsementWithin10Days_Counts.csv'
$pathDetails = Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath 'BoundPoliciesAddedAtFaultEndorsementWithin10Days_Details.csv'
$date = Get-Date
$dateStr = $date.ToString("yyyyMM")

# Define combined file name
$outFile = Join-Path $path -ChildPath("BoundPoliciesAddedAtFaultEndorsementsWithin10Days_" + $dateStr + ".csv")

# Execute combine files code
Get-Content $pathCounts, $pathDetails | Set-Content $outFile
```

Here is an image of what Step #2 looks like:

[image]

Comment: Post the *script*, not a screenshot of the script. In any case the error is clear - that path can't be found. Either the actual string is wrong or the Agent service account doesn't have to read from that path. Perhaps it doesn't have permissions to read that file share. What happens when that script runs in a Powershell windo?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Unfortunately, I cannot login to the SQL server to execute the powershell code from that environment as they have us pretty well locked down where I work.

Comment: Do it on your own machine. There's nothing special in that script. It looks like simple file concatenation. If *you* can't run it, even though you can access that path, it means the service account has no permission to access that file share.

Comment: As I stated previously above, I can run the script locally from my box and it runs successfully within Powershell ISE.

Comment: THen you need to add permissions to that file share to allow the service account to connect. Is it a local or domain account? Local accounts, or the NETWORK account can't be recognized by other machines and they appear as the source machine's computer account. If you want the SQL Server Agent service account to have access to file shares you should use a Domain account with sufficient priviledges

Comment: Thanks.  I'll get with server admin.

Comment: I just got a message from the server admin stating that the service DOMAIN account has MODIFY RIGHTS and is a member of the Domain Admins and has FULL CONTROL RIGHTS on the share folder.  Is there anything else I can ask be checked to clear up this issue?  Thanks.